# How can I crack a 16 bit hash/CRC/checksum with a large sample set?

Tags: hash, cryptography, checksum

I have some traffic packets with two bytes that looks like random numbers, I suspect this is a 16 bit signature of some kind. It could be a checksum of some sort, a CRC, or a hash.

Each packet is 64 bytes long (with a structure that I am very close to understanding), I get one packet every 4 milliseconds, so 250 reports per second. I can capture a few hours worth of this data if I need to.

Since there are only two bytes that exhibit this random behaviour, I suspect there to be only 65536 possible hashes.

So given my capability to capture a large sample set and probably only need to deal with 16 bits. What are some ways I can use these samples to figure out how to generate the same hash for an arbitrary packet that I generate myself?

EDIT: the device generating these packets is a ARM Cortex M4, probably top speed of roughly 160 MHz, to give you an idea of how much computational power it has so to narrow down the possibilities. It could have dedicated cryptography hardware (AES engine, RNG, hash engine, etc) though.

Comment: Can you choose the data content of the packets and observe the effect it has on the checksum?

Comment: This question might do better on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/